# How can you get boost::program_options working with boost::posix_time::ptime?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options, boost-date-time

I've made several attemps at getting this working to no avail. The program compiles but every timestamp format I can think of for supplying to the program is invalid.

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace boost::program_options;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    boost::posix_time::ptime forceDate;
    boost::optional<boost::posix_time::ptime> forceDateOptional;

    options_description descr("Options");
    descr.add_options()
    ("force-date,a", value(&forceDate)->value_name("<date>"), "...");

    try {
        variables_map args;
        store(command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(descr).run(), args);
        notify(args);
        cout << "Done." << endl;
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_program_options -lboost_system x.cpp` and run with `./a.out --force-date 2012-01-03`.

Here is the error from the exception thrown:

```
the argument ('2012-01-03') for option '--force-date' is invalid
```

Comment: Is it failing to compile or failing to run? show the error messages.

Comment: Failing to run. I've given the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first try to simplify your example by removing `program_options` and simply trying to parse `posix_time::ptime` from a stream.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime forceDate;
std::istringstream ss("2012-01-03");
if(ss >> forceDate) {
    std::cout << forceDate << "\n";
}
```

The above example prints nothing, so clearly something's going wrong with the parsing. If you look up the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_operators) for `operator>>` it becomes evident that the expected format for the month is an abbreviated name instead of a numeric value.

If you change the above code to

```
boost::posix_time::ptime forceDate;
std::istringstream ss("2012-Jan-03");
if(ss >> forceDate) {
    std::cout << forceDate << "\n";
}
```

it produces the desired output.

More digging through the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#time_facet_intro) shows the way to control the input format is using `boost::posix_time::time_input_facet`. The `set_iso_extended_format` sets the format to the numeric format you want to use.

```
boost::posix_time::ptime forceDate;
std::istringstream ss("2012-01-03");

auto facet = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet();
facet->set_iso_extended_format();

ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), facet));
if(ss >> forceDate) {
    std::cout << forceDate << "\n";
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e183ef4d401daf20)

---

Back to `program_options` now. It doesn't look like the library offers locale support directly, so the only way I can get the above solution to work is by messing with the global locale. If you add the following lines to your example, it behaves as you want it to.

```
auto facet = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet();
facet->set_iso_extended_format();
std::locale::global(std::locale(std::locale(), facet));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eabb4e18ce13d788)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I particularly appreciated the detail in diagnosing the problem (date time formatting with the use of locales) and providing a solution (the global locale).

Comment: I'll be awarding you a bounty of 50 rep to show my appreciation.

Comment: @user1420752 Thanks for all the rep. The bounty really wasn't necessary, but I appreciate the gesture. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe not, but I was kicking myself over this issue and was under pressure to get it done, so I appreciated getting a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your code and compile it on Ubuntu 14.04-- I got the same results you did. So I passed the date into a `std::string` and then attempted to construct a `boost::posix_time::ptime` from that:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace boost::program_options;
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char ** argv) {
    auto dateStr = string {};
    auto descr = options_description { "Options" };

    descr.add_options ()
        ("help,h", "produce help message")
        ("date,a", value (&dateStr)->value_name ("<date>"), "...");

    try {
        auto args = variables_map {};
        store (command_line_parser (argc, argv).options (descr).run (), args);
        notify (args);

        auto forceDate = boost::posix_time::ptime { dateStr };

        cout << "Done." << endl;
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception & e) {
        cout << e.what () << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I had to dig around a little before finding out that [according to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477177/undefined-reference-to-boostgregoriangreg-monthas-short-string-const) you must link `boost_date_time`. I used the following script to compile and re-run at the same time:

`rerun.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -o main.x64 -std=c++11 -I . -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu main.cpp -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lboost_date_time
./main.x64 --date "2012-01-01"
```

and this is the final code I used to get it to run:

`main.cpp`

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace boost::program_options;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char ** argv) {
        auto dateStr = string {};
        auto descr = options_description { "Options" };

        descr.add_options ()
                ("date,a", value (&dateStr)->value_name ("<date>"), "...");

        try {
                auto args = variables_map {};
                store (command_line_parser (argc, argv).options (descr).run (), args);
                notify (args);

                // this is the important part.
                auto d = boost::gregorian::date {
                        boost::gregorian::from_simple_string (dateStr)
                };

                auto forceDate = boost::posix_time::ptime { d };

                cout << "Done." << endl;
                return 0;

        } catch (std::exception & e) {
                cout << e.what () << endl;
                return 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: The problem with `time_from_string` is that if you use the input format the OP wants to use (`2012-01-01`), which contains only a date and not a time, the parsing fails.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Praetorian. I've fixed it now to use the format OP was using.